# Django class overrides fails System check

Tags: python, django, overriding, models

I am trying to upgrade from Django 1.7.1 to 1.8 on my dev env. I seem to be having an issue with one of my models, I think a core file got upgraded and its messing with my model. I cant seem to figure out what's causing it to die.

This is the only error I get when I attempt to run a manage.py test

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
graphite_alerts.CheckResults: (models.E020) The 'CheckResults.check()' class method is currently   overridden by <django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object at 0x3a76310>.
```

I tried changing the class name and looked around my model and cant seem to find anything that would be causing an override error

This is the class:

```
class CheckResults(models.Model):

    WARN = 'warn'
    ERROR = 'error'
    OK = 'ok'
    DOWN = 'down'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (WARN, 'Warn'),
        (ERROR, 'Error'),
        (OK, 'OK'),
        (DOWN, 'Down'),
    )

    target = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    additional_graph_target = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='ok')
    check = models.ForeignKey(Check, related_name='results')
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.target

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('graphite-check-result-list-view', (), {'pk': self.check.pk, 'target': self.target})

    def generate_graphite_image_url(self):
        params = { }
        params['target'] = []
        params['target'].append(self.target)
        params['target'].append('threshold(' + str(self.check.warn) + ',"Warn","yellow")')
        params['target'].append('threshold(' + str(self.check.error) + ',"Error","red")')
        params['from'] = '-7days'
        params['width'] = '900'
        params['minorGridLineColor'] = 'C0C0C0'
        params['majorGridLineColor'] = 'C0C0C0'
        params['bgcolor'] = '333333'
        request = requests.get(self.check.GRAPHITE_URL+self.check.RENDER_PAGE,params=params)
        return urllib2.unquote(request.url.decode('UTF-8'))

    def generate_additional_graphite_image_url(self):
        params = { }
        params['target'] = []
        params['target'].append(self.additional_graph_target)
        params['target'].append('threshold(' + str(self.check.warn) + ',"Warn","yellow")')
        params['target'].append('threshold(' + str(self.check.error) + ',"Error","red")')
        params['from'] = '-7days'
        params['width'] = '900'
        params['minorGridLineColor'] = 'C0C0C0'
        params['majorGridLineColor'] = 'C0C0C0'
        params['bgcolor'] = '333333'
        request = requests.get(self.check.GRAPHITE_URL+self.check.RENDER_PAGE,params=params)
        return urllib2.unquote(request.url.decode('UTF-8'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("timestamp",)
        unique_together = (("target", "timestamp"),)
```

Comment: Django 1.8 has not been released yet. Stick with 1.7.X for now.

Comment: Thanks! I just finished doing some more investigation and it seems the newer versions dont like having variables named after classes. I had a Class Check, and a variable Check. just need to figure out how to make them work together! Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while updating a project from 1.6 to 1.8.

The issue seems to stem from the `check` field that your model has.
It conflicts with the `Model.check()` method, which is called during [Django's  system checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/checks/) to help you identify errors in model definition.

You'll have to rename the field.

Comment: Thanks K. Tomov, I actually forgot to update this. I ended up changing the check() field to check_field() and it works fine!