# Django class method is currently overridden

Tags: django, django-models

This is the error when I tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations` in command line

```
ERRORS:
asking.Question: (models.E020) The 'Question.check()' class method is currently overridden by <function BaseManager.check at 0x7f0f104889d8>.
```

This is `Question` class in `models.py`:

```
class Question(BaseModel):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    answer = models.TextField("answer", blank=True, null=True)
    answerer = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="questions"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

And this is BaseModel class:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.models import SoftDeletableManager, TimeStampedModel


class BaseModel(SoftDeletableManager, TimeStampedModel, models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I am using Django version 2.0.5

Comment: Did you change this model? How was it before the changes?

Comment: I did not change a model before

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the User model? could you provide it?

Comment: You could change BaseModel in Model if you don't need it for other reasons

Comment: I am using User model in django.contrib.auth.models

Comment: Your link. It's me

Comment: Sorry I meant this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607988/django-class-overrides-fails-system-check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `BaseModel` derives from `SoftDeletableManager` and not `SoftDeletableModel`.

e.g change to:

```
class BaseModel(SoftDeletableModel, TimeStampedModel, models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The manager should be set as a model property

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.models import SoftDeletableManager, TimeStampedModel


class BaseModel(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):

    objects = SoftDeletableManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```